# App version missing AIR 3.1 Mobile Android

Tags: android, air

After updating to Flex 4.6 and AIR 3.1 application version is missing from Manage Applications > Application Info on a Android Devices.

It is visible while compiling with AIR 2.6 and Flex 4.5

both app descriptors contains

```
<versionNumber>1.0.1</versionNumber>
<versionLabel>1.0.1</versionLabel>
```

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to some errors when Adobe packaging tools generate apk file.

Since apk is just a zip you can rename and extract it, find androidmanifest.xml and see what happened.